# How can I change node name of my JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I change the name of a node in my JSON?

My code:

```
childType = view
childName = view0

child=[];
    child[childTipy]= { 
                childType:{
                    "tipo": childTipy,
                    "nome":childName,
                }
            };

childList.push(child[childTipy]);

minhasWindows =  {"window": {
                        "nome": "Win2",
                        "title": "Win",
                        "childrens": childList
                    }
};
```

The resulting JSON:

```
{
    "windows" : [
        {
            "window" : {
                "nome" : "Win2",
                "title" : "Win",
                "childrens" : [
                    {
                        "childType" : {
                            "tipo" : "view",
                            "nome" : "view0"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the `childType` node to be the value of my `var childType = "view"`. How can I change this?

PS: I have multiple `childType` values.

Comment: I would highly recommend not creating and editing JSON yourself. JQuery has a bunch of built in functions to serialize and deserialize JSON for you.

Comment: There is no jQuery here.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Its one of the tags of the question.

Comment: The question is confusing. Are you trying to use a variable as a key in a object? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-to-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable

Comment: What is the relationship between the first and second code snippets? Are you creating JSON from JavaScript objects? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the property to come from a variable, use array syntax to assign the property.

```
var childType = "view"; // String needs to be quoted
var childName = "view0"; // String needs to be quoted
var child = {}; // This must be an object, not array
child[childType] = {
   tipo: childType, // Don't need to quote keys in object literals
   nome: childName,
};
childList.push(child);
```

You also had too many levels in your `child` object.

Comment: My json return: {"windows":[{"window":{"nome":"Win2","title":"Win","width":"auto","height":"auto","fullscreen":"true","modal":"true","main":"true","childrens":[[]]}}]} i'm use add this "childList.push(child[childType]);"

Comment: Is `childTypy` the same as `childType`?

Comment: Is `childTypy` a number or string? You can't use a string as an index in an array, so you can't initialize `var child = [];`. If it's a string `child` has to be an object, `var child = {};`.

Comment: I didn't ask about `childType`, I asked about `childTypy`. Or is one of those a typo?

Comment: I have "N" elements with different values ​​for both properties as to the name of "childType", what need is the node "childType" is the value of the variable "childType"

Comment: This general structure should work. If it doesn't, please update your question with your attempt to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
childType:{
```

to

```
view:{
```

Comment: i have multiples childType values =/

Comment: What is "view"? Is it a variable that you are assigning values to? If yes, where? If it's just a string lateral, simply change `childType = view` to `childType = "view"`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
child=[];
child[childTipy]= { 
            childType:{
                "tipo": childTipy,
                "nome":childName,
            }
        };
```

with

```
child=[];
child[childTipy]= {};
child[childTipy][childType] = {
                "tipo": childTipy,
                "nome":childName,
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

If `childType` appears in the keys only:

```
var someJson = '{"windows":[{"window":{"nome":"Win2","title":"Win","childrens":[{"childType":{"tipo":"view","nome":"view0"}}]}}]}';

var newJson = $.parseJSON(someJson.replace('childType', 'view'));
```

Though I don't see any actual need of changing a key in place.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'

Comment: Be careful: in my code `someJson` is a JSON string, not an object. If you have an object already, serialize it to a string before [e.g. `JSON.stringify(someJson)`].

Comment: Doing a string replacement in the JSON string seems like a very dangerous way to implement this.

Comment: @Barmar actually _this_ should not be implemented at all, because there is a clear design flaw at the top - this is just a dirty hack.