# How to programmatically create object keys in initializer?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I want to initialize with dynamically named keys. I know I can do it in code like this:

```
obj = {};
prefix = "blah";
i = 0;
obj[prefix + i] = "whatever";
console.log( obj.blah0 );
```

e.g. like from here: [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-to-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

But can this be done in an initializer?

```
obj = { [prefix+i]: "whatever" };
```

I know that doesn't work. I tried it. But is there a similar method that does work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't dynamically generate keys in object literals in the current version of JavaScript.

You *can* use an anonymous function as a constructor, and generate key-value pairs that way:

```
obj = new function() {
    var i,
        prefix;
    prefix = 'blah';
    i = 0;
    this[prefix + i] = "whatever";
};
console.log(obj.blah0); //"whatever"
```