# Grunt uglify : Weird behavior

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I cannot figure out why uglify does not want concat string as input or output ...

This works :

```
uglify: {
    dev_uglify_js: {
        files: {
            'my_file.min.js': ['my_file.js']
        }
    }
}
```

For example, this does not works :

```
uglify: {
    dev_uglify_js: {
        files: {
            'my'+'_file.min.js': ['my_file.js']
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why ? 
The output error is "SyntaxError: Unexpected token".

The real insterest here is to concatenate a timestamp to the file name.
But just with 2 strings it does not work so ...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, an object `key` cannot be **declared** dynamically. This is not a problem with `grunt` or `uglify` - it's a language constraint.

```
myObject = { 'a' + 'b' : 'b' } // NOPE!
```

However, any object property can be accessed via square brackets. For example:

```
myObject = { 'banana': 'boat' }
myObject.banana // boat
myObject['banana'] // boat!
```

Therefore, you **can** add properties after the object is already created, using the square brackets syntax.

```
myObject = {} 
myObject[ 'a' + 'b' ] = 'b' // Yes
myObject.ab // b
```

#### The Gruntfile example

In your Gruntfile, you're bound to, at  some point, call something like `grunt.config.init` or `grunt.initConfig`. This is usually done inline:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {} // properties ...
});
```

However, `initConfig` simply receives an object. You can define it and manipulate it as much as you need before calling this function. So, for example:

```
var config = { uglify: {} };
config.uglify['such'+'dynamic'+'very'+'smarts'] = {};
grunt.initConfig(config);
```

Similar questions:

[How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-to-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

[How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: Thx for your answer gadr90 :). I read both subjects and indeed they are related to my question. But still ... I don't understand. How can i have a dynamic name file for uglify ?

Comment: I feel quite dumb on this one, i spent 3hours looking for ideas but nothing work.

Comment: Hey, @Maxime, there are no dumb questions! I think you don't realize that the grunt configuration object is just that - an object. You don't need to declare it inline. See if my expanded answer is more fitting, and congrats on your determination!

Comment: Ok then ! In my grunt i have many tasks. Not only the uglify one. Do i have to declare them before the grunt init ? Could you edit and add some code to your last code example ? Because i don't understand

Comment: You can declare your entire config before and call `initConfig` on the last line, if you want :)

Comment: I declared the config before the initConfig and now it works !! :D !!
Thank you so much gadr90, and i checked your blog you write interesting articles ! Keep going ! (you saved my night haha). Pb marked as solved ;)