# Reactjs setState() with a dynamic key name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, computed-properties

EDIT: this is a duplicate, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-to-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

I can't find any examples of using a dynamic key name when setting the state.  This is what I want to do:

```
inputChangeHandler : function (event) {
    this.setState( { event.target.id  : event.target.value } );
},
```

where event.target.id is used as the state key to be updated.  Is this not possible in React?

Comment: This is a duplicate of any question concerning dynamic object keys. It's not specific to react

Comment: var newstate = {}; newstate[event.target.id] = event.target.id; this.setState(newstate);

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have a good handle on using objects in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Comment: @trad I'm with this problem but, what did you put on your initial State? It doesn't matter, right?

Answer (score 325):

Thanks to @Cory's hint, i used this:

```
inputChangeHandler : function (event) {
    var stateObject = function() {
      returnObj = {};
      returnObj[this.target.id] = this.target.value;
         return returnObj;
    }.bind(event)();

    this.setState( stateObject );    
},
```

If using ES6 or the [Babel transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) to transform your JSX code, you can accomplish this with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), too:

```
inputChangeHandler : function (event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
    // alternatively using template strings for strings
    // this.setState({ [`key${event.target.id}`]: event.target.value });
}
```

Comment: There's also a new syntax for this, if you're using bablejs to build your code. You can use `computed property names`

Comment: The second approach causes syntax error in browsers on WIndows (IE, Chrome). Did anyone notice?

Comment: how to get stated?

Comment: Thanks `trad`, this is what i was looking for to avoid code duplication for `<Radio />` implementation.

Comment: If you set a state using the computed property name like this: `this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });` then how would you access that state using `this.state......`?

Comment: how do I access that state in same way ? like this.state([event.target.name])

Comment: Is there  a way to add property inside? Something like this.setState({[`${newFormName}.${uniqueId}`]: uniqueId })    ?

Comment: you can use this.state[event.target.id] to read state

Answer (score 184):

When you need to handle multiple controlled input elements, you can add a name attribute to each element and let the handler function choose what to do based on the value of event.target.name.

For example:

```js
inputChangeHandler(event) {
  this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

Comment: what do the brackets around [event.target.name] indicate? Why are they required?

Comment: As compared to usual approach to named each element separately like
this.setState({ userName: e.target.value });

This will handle multiple elements of form as an array and no need to set each individual element

Comment: but still how do I access that state in same way ? like `this.state([event.target.name])` ?

Comment: I think [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [this post](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/understanding-this-setstate-name-value-a5ef7b4ea2b4) explains why we need the brackets.

Answer (score 50):

How I accomplished this...

```
inputChangeHandler: function(event) {
  var key = event.target.id
  var val = event.target.value
  var obj  = {}
  obj[key] = val
  this.setState(obj)
},
```

Comment: I did similar way but the problem was it still did not render the component, and I ran pillar to post (including this :D), and somewhere found this: `this.forceUpdate();`which should not have been the case with latest React. Let's see whats the issue later!!

Answer (score 32):

I just wanted to add, that you can also use de-structuring to refactor the code and make it look neater.

```
inputChangeHandler: function ({ target: { id, value }) {
    this.setState({ [id]: value });
},
```

Answer (score 15):

```
this.setState({ [`${event.target.id}`]: event.target.value}, () => {
      console.log("State updated: ", JSON.stringify(this.state[event.target.id]));
    });
```

Please mind the quote character.

Comment: exactly what i needed.

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked. However could you explain what the `[ ]` do? Why does react require that?

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem.

I wanted to set the state of where the 2nd level key was stored in a variable.

e.g. `this.setState({permissions[perm.code]: e.target.checked})`

However this isn't valid syntax.

I used the following code to achieve this:

```
this.setState({
  permissions: {
    ...this.state.permissions,
    [perm.code]: e.target.checked
  }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

In loop with `.map` work like this:

```
{
    dataForm.map(({ id, placeholder, type }) => {
        return <Input
            value={this.state.type}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ [type]: text })}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            key={id} />
    })
}
```

Note the `[]` in `type` parameter.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a pretty and simple solution and I found this:

```
this.setState({ [`image${i}`]: image })
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

With ES6+ you can just do [`${variable}`]

Answer (score 2):

when the given element is a object:

```
handleNewObj = e => {
        const data = e[Object.keys(e)[0]];
        this.setState({
            anykeyofyourstate: {
                ...this.state.anykeyofyourstate,
                [Object.keys(e)[0]]: data
            }
        });
    };
```

hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Your state with dictionary update some key without losing other value

```
state = 
{   
    name:"mjpatel"  
    parsedFilter:
    {
      page:2,
      perPage:4,
      totalPages: 50,
    }
}
```

Solution is below

```
 let { parsedFilter } = this.state
 this.setState({
      parsedFilter: {
        ...this.state.parsedFilter,
        page: 5
      }
  });
```

here update value for key "page" with value 5

Comment: setState should return a new object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JS ES6+, it is `[${variable}]`, to set the key:

```js
// In React
onChange={e => setData({ [variable] : e.target.value })}
```

As well, if you want to access the dynamic key, you just use `data[${variable}]`:

```js
// In React
value={data[variable]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one please.

State is here as example

```
 this.state = {
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            username: '',
            email: '',
  }
```

Onchange function is here.

```
onChangeData = (type, event) => {
    const stateData = this.state;
    if (event === "" || event === "Seçiniz")
        stateData[type] = undefined
    else
        stateData[type] = event

    this.setState({ stateData});
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Can use a spread syntax, something like this:

```
inputChangeHandler : function (event) {
    this.setState( { 
        ...this.state,
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    } );
},
```

Comment: React will do the object merging for you, this is bad practice.

Comment: basically if you have some inner object and you want to change one propery on that inner object you do it like this: 

this.setState({selectedItems:{...selectedItems,[item.id]:true}})

Comment: @Rohmer : Why is this considered a bad practice ? If an object has multiple keys, using the spread operator seems to work to preserve all other keys except the one being modified. Or should we use prevState ? Please explain.

Comment: If you have nested state like @EranOr mentioned, then doing spread makes sense, but you must use `prevState` or you won’t be able to guarantee that you’re using the most up-to-date state. However, if you’re just setting a single, top-level state value like in @sta’s answer, then you don’t need to spread on state since React will merge it in for you. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged