# React.js setState() with variable for key inside loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to use a string variable's value as the key for setState()?

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        foo: '',
        bar: ''
    }
}

someOtherHandler: function() {
    var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
    var _this = this;
    var number = Math.random();

    for (var i in arr) {
        _this.setState({ arr[i]: number });
    }

}
```

React throws a syntax error with the above, and setting arr[i] to a variable ends up setting a new state with that variable's name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create the object before calling `setState`.

```
var newState = {};
newState[i] = number;
_this.setState(newState);
```

Alternatively if you are using ES6, you could make use of a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```
_this.setState({ [i]: number });
```

However this code will call `setState` multiple times, it's more efficient to only call it once. Build the updated state object, then apply it.

```
var newState = {};

for(var i in arr) {
  newState[i] = number;
}

this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had actually just run across a similar question that essentially pointed me to the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280445/reactjs-setstate-with-a-dynamic-key-name