# how to send input data taken dynamically to the server using POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

class Modals extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputuuid: '',
    inputmajor: '' ,
    inputminor: '' ,
    inputmanufacturer: ''};
    this.handleUuid = this.handleUuid.bind(this);
    this.handleMajor = this.handleMajor.bind(this);
    this.handleMinor = this.handleMinor.bind(this);
    this.handleManufacturer = this.handleManufacturer.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    alert("started");
fetch("http://api-env.bt2qjip33m.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/beacons" ,
 {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGMyOTdiOWQzZWM4NjY4MDMwNDBlNjgiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImtrQGxpdGlmZXIuY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaGxheSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaG9yZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ4OTE0NzgzM30.nHW5w3SSov8ySziblmw2VNlGI3CsZFR-v41Jeg9uBVs'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "beacon name 1234",
    description: "beacon description here for beacon",
    uuid: "this.state.inputuuid1",
    major: "this.state.inputmajor",
    minor: "this.state.inputminor",
    manufacturer: "this.state.inputmanufacturer",
    beaconType: "type9",
    location: "main gate8",
    floor: "ist",
    zone: "58c29c06d3ec866803040e6e"
})
}).then(function(response){
  if(response.ok) {
      console.log(response)
    return response;
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(data) { 
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error);
});
}

handleUuid(event) {

    this.setState({inputuuid: event.target.value});
  }
  handleMajor(event){
    this.setState({inputmajor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleMinor(event){
    this.setState({inputminor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleManufacturer(event){
        this.setState({inputmanufacturer: event.target.value});
  }
handleSubmit(event) {

    alert('Submitted: ' + this.state.inputuuid + this.state.inputmajor + this.state.inputminor + this.state.inputmanufacturer);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 57 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Beacon Settings
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text"  className="form-control" value={this.state.inputuuid} onChange={this.handleUuid} placeholder="UUID" />
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputmajor} onChange={this.handleMajor} placeholder="Major Number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputminor} onChange={this.handleMinor} placeholder="Minor Number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputmanufacturer} onChange={this.handleManufacturer} placeholder="Manufacturer Number"/>
                </div><center>
                <Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success"  onClick={this.handleSubmit} activeClassName="active">Save</Link>

<Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Advance Settings</Link>
</center>

            </div>
          </div>
</div></div>
      </div>
      
        
      
    )
  }
}

export default Modals;
```

i had taken the user inputs now i want to send them to the server using POST request which i can not able to send.
i am only getting the values by the user and those can be seen by the alert i had put in that but can't able to send to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using following way

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  firstParam: 'yourValue',
  secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
 })
});
```

React require stringify post body data

Comment: is it get calling api, have you checked in network tab

Comment: server has to set headers so that call from any where

Answer (score 0):

You can create your inputField like this:

```
<input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.userData.firstName} required placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'firstName')} />
```

In your form component, you can define userData state object in this way:

```
this.state = {
  userData: {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    ...
  }
}
```

And for handleChange(), we can make it to accept dynamic keys for state variables:

```
handleChange(key, e, value){
  let data = this.state.userData;
  userData[key] = e.target.value;
  this.setState({
    userData: data
  });
}
```

All you need to post then is this.state.userData.

Comment: i had taken the inputs but the problem is in posting that data to the server

Comment: Did you get any error message from the response? Or could that be CORS issue? The fetch request looks good to me. Is that token valid and can you double check the server with Postman?

Comment: Please change the fetch body to non-string variable. You are passing the string "this.state.xxx" as the value to your server at the moment.

Comment: Ah, and you need to call fetch() function in your handleSubmit too! You put it in the wrong place. There is only alert() and that's why you only see the alert message with the data!

Comment: i did that too what u said to put fetch in handleSubmit
its still not posting any data to the server