# How to multiple TextInput handle with single handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-0.46

I have create common class for TextInput and use it multiple time but its event handle with same method. i want to handle array data after filled the data in textInput.

Here Added multiple textField and single `handleAddMore`. How to identify which textInput called the `handleAddMore`.

The textField component added dynamically according to array data. now when user edit the textInput I want to identify the textInput and updated array text on particular index.

```
let addMoreCompView = this.state.dataAddMore.map((data ,index) =>{
 return(
   <View style ={[styles.commonMargin ,{flexDirection : 'row',marginTop : 2 , height : 40, backgroundColor : Globle.COLOR.INPUTCOLOR}]}>
     <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '80%' , justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection : 'column'}}>
         <TextInput style = {{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Light',fontSize : 14 ,color: Globle.COLOR.BACKCOLOR , paddingLeft : 20}}
              underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
              placeholder = 'Please enter emailID.'
              placeholderTextColor = 'black'
              autoCapitalize = "none"
              keyboardType = "email-address"
              onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
              onChangeText = {this.handleAddMore}
              autoCorrect = {false}/>
     </View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.removeMoreComponent(data.key)} style = {{height : '90%' , width : '20%' , alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
       <Image style = {{width : 9 , height : 10 , marginRight : 20}} source = {require('./Images/cancelMore.png')}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
 )
});
```

Here I want to identify which `TextInput` called this method.

Here I want to text and index of textField.

```
 handleAddMore = (text) =>{

    // Here I want to text and index of textField.
 }
```

Comment: Please check this ref link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280445/reactjs-setstate-with-a-dynamic-key-name

Comment: best thing to use redux-form , http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/faq/reactnative.md/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
_handleMultiInput(name) {
    return (text) => {
        this.setState({ [name]:text })
    }
}

<TextInput
   placeholder='enter your name.'
   onChangeText={_handleMultiInput('myName')}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just pass another parameter to `handleAddMore`?

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = 'Please enter emailID.'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {(text) => { this.handleAddMore(text, 'textInput1'); }}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>

handleAddMore = (text, textInput) => {

}
```

---

**Update 1**

[onChangeText](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext) receives `text` as parameter and [onChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchange) receives `event`

---

**Update 2**

I created a small project to show you how it works. You can check the code and implement it to your project as you wish. You not explaining the error exactly makes it harder to find whats wrong with your code exactly. Saying *not working* **is never enough**. You can find the project on **[Here](https://snack.expo.io/H1zqlGKqZ)** (Expo)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: '',
      inputCount: 3,
      data: [{ name: 'input1' }, { name: 'input2' }, { name: 'input3' }],
    };
    this.inputRefs = {};
  }

  onAddMore() {
    const newData = this.state.data;
    newData.push({ name: `input${this.state.inputCount + 1}` });
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      inputCount: prevState.inputCount + 1,
      data: newData,
    }));
  }

  _onChangeText(text, inputName) {
    console.log('Input Name:', inputName, text);
    console.log("Inout's Ref:", this.inputRefs[inputName]);
    const info = `${this.state.info}\n\r${inputName} changed text`;
    this.setState({
      info
    });
  }

  _onChange(event, inputName) {
    console.log('Input Name:', inputName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.data.map(d => (
          <View style={styles.inputWrapper} key={d.name}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={(text) => { this._onChangeText(text, d.name); }}
              onChange={(event) => { this._onChange(event, d.name); }}
              ref={ref => {
                this.inputRefs[d.name] = ref;
              }}
              defaultValue={d.name}
            />
          </View>
        ))}
        <Button
          onPress={this.onAddMore.bind(this)}
          title="Add More"
          color="#841584"
        />
        <TextInput
          multiline={true}
          editable={false}
          style={styles.info}>
            {this.state.info}
          </TextInput>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
  },
  info: {
    flex: 0.5,
  },
  inputWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    marginTop: 5,
    marignBottom: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  input: {
    height: 55,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: @KiritModi _"not working"_ is not enough of information.

Comment: The textField component added dynamically according to array data. now when user edit the textInput I want to identify the textInput and updated array text on particular index.

Comment: @KiritModi still doesn't explain _not working_ part. What is not working? What error do you get if you get any? There might be something wrong on your _dynamically adding_ part. Maybe I could help more if you give more information.

Comment: I will update question with GIF so You can easily get.

Comment: I want to adding textFiled dynamically, in iOS there are tag so that we can handle it. but in rect not ant tag.

Comment: see this code how to add textField on click on AddMore button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154520/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-bennygenel).

Comment: Please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551462/how-to-drag-and-drop-with-multiple-view-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

The code bellow works for react but not for react native: "onChangeText" pass only the text. There's another method called "onChange" that passes the input itself, but on react native it doesn't pass the input (because RN works for both android/iOS/web, and Android/iOS don't have an event.target)

Add `name` to TextInputs

```
<TextInput
  name='input1'
  placeholder = 'Please enter emailID.'
  onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
  onChange = {(e) => this.handleAddMore(e.target.name)}
  autoCorrect = {false}
/>
<TextInput
  name='input2'
  placeholder = 'Please enter emailID.'
  onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
  onChange = {(e) => this.handleAddMore(e.target.name)}
  autoCorrect = {false}
/>
```

and define handleAddMore as:

```
handleAddMore = (name) =>{
  //add your code here
}
```

Comment: @KiritModi Have you implemented the `TextInput` component yourself or are you using this from some library?

Comment: No its default component.

Comment: The textField component added dynamically according to array data. now when user edit the textinput I want to identify the textInput and updated array text on particular index.

Comment: And why don't the above answers help you?

Comment: its get only Text inside the method. I want also reference of textInput.

Comment: Then giving names to TextInputs and passing those in onChangeText should work. Have you tried any of the above answers, do you get any errors?

Comment: I can't get the object's.target.name. It throws an error for me

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary It's hard to help without looking at the code.

Comment: All I am saying is that in react native, using the same code, it doesn't give me object.target.name. Cause object is undefined in that case

Comment: I don't have much idea about react native, does the accepted answer not work for you? @SiddharthChoudhary

Comment: @Aanchal1103 Have you find any soulation?

Comment: This works for react but not for react native: "onChangeText" pass only the text. There's another method called "onChange" that passes the input itself, but on react native it doesn't pass the input.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `name` attribute in textInput. In future if you will need to update current state field you can handle it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
 state = { val1: '', val2: '' };

 handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

 render(){
  const { val1, val2 } = this.state;
  console.log(val1, val2);
  return(
   <div>
    <TextInput
     name="val1"
     value={val1}
     placeholder = 'Please enter emailID.'
     onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
     onChangeText = {this.handleChange}
     autoCorrect = {false}/>

    <TextInput
     name="val2"
     value={val2}
     placeholder = 'Please enter emailID.'
     onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
     onChangeText = {this.handleChange}
     autoCorrect = {false}/>
   </div>    
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: @KiritModi, yes, i edit to full component for you. If you need i can write child component - TextInput for you if you develop it for web, nor for ios/android.

Answer (score 0):

Using functional component. I have three inputs amount, date and description to save. Here is how to save them in single object and using same function for all three TextInput.

```
 // useState hook to store object
     const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
        amount: '',
        date: '',
        description: '',
      });

      // will save user input
      function inputChangeHandler(inputIdentifier, enteredValue) {
        setInputValues(currentInputValues => {
           return {
              ...currentInputValues, 
              [inputIdentifier]: enteredValue, // dynamically override the desired input
           };
        });
       }

    // TextInput Component
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={inputChangeHandler.bind(this, 'amount')}
              value={inputValues.amount}
              placeholder={inputValues.title}
            />
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={inputChangeHandler.bind(this, 'date')}
              value={inputValues.date}
              placeholder={inputValues.title}
            />
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={inputChangeHandler.bind(this, 'description')}
              value={inputValues.date}
              placeholder={inputValues.title}
            />
```