# react setState with dynamic key

Tags: reactjs

I have the following snippet of code:

```
onChange(e) {
    e.persist
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState[e.target.id] =  e.target.value
      return prevState
    })
  }
```

the how would i set the state for each key using something like the code above.

this is the initial state:

```
 this.state = {
      heading: this.props.match.params.length > 1 ? "Edit Post" : "Create Post",
      title: '',
      category: '',
      body: '',
      author: ''
    }
```

Comment: so what is the question? the code in the `onChange` will set a dynamic state key as the id of your event element. you don't need to persist the event - just do `const { target: { value, id } } = e` then just use `id` and `value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactjs setState() with a dynamic key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280445/reactjs-setstate-with-a-dynamic-key-name)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Basic rule is:**

We can use [**Computed property names**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) concept and use any **js expression** to compute the object property name dynamically. For that we need to put the expression inside `[]`.

Like this:

```js
var obj = {
   [10 * 20 + 1 - 5]: "Hello"
};

console.log('obj = ', obj);
```

**Solution:**

As per the code you posted, you need to put `e.target.id` inside `[]`, like this:

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

Or we can create that object first, then pass that object to `setState` function, like this:

```
onChange(e) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[e.target.id] = e.target.value
    this.setState(obj);
}
```

Also you don't need the `prevState`. You can directly update the state variable with new value.`prevState` is required only when new state value is dependent on previous state value, like in case of counter.

Comment: I tried that before, but i get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: that means you forgot to bind the `onChange` method, put this line in the constructor: `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)` :)