# Creating a handler for fluent ui drop down, using a dynamic name for a React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a drop down:

```
  <Dropdown
    id="JobPlanDD"
    selectedKey={(this.state["JobPlanDD-option"]) ? (this.state["JobPlanDD-option"]).key : undefined}
    placeholder="Select..."
    onChange={(e, i) => this.handleChange(e, i)} 
    options={jobPlanDDOptions}                                 
    />
```

And I have a handler for that drop down and any others I make in the future:

```
 const id = evt.target.querySelector('span').id;
  const theItem = item.text;

  this.setState({ 
    [id]: theItem 

  });
```

For this particular drop down I've been told to use `JobPlanDD-option` in the `selectedKey` property but I don't understand why.

I manage to log the id of the of the particular drop down thanks to the handler
`const id = evt.target.querySelector('span').id;`

but it returns `JobPlanDD-option` which can't be a state because it has a hyphen or minus.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

I have read this and although it describes much, it doesn't completely pertain to my question:
[Reactjs setState() with a dynamic key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280445/reactjs-setstate-with-a-dynamic-key-name)

Comment: "but it returns JobPlanDD-option which can't be a state because it has a hyphen or minus."

Sure it can, after all, state is just an object, and the keys can be strings of any kind.

Comment: console.log(this.state["JobPlanDD-option"], 'state.JobPlanDD')
Yes! Your nudge worked. Should have guessed! 
I'll update with an answer
@lanxion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a nudge with this one:
The dynamic state *was being set*, it was just how I needed to write it in order to use it:

```
console.log(this.state["JobPlanDD-option"], 'state.JobPlanDD')
```

Staring me in the face...