# How do I dynamically name an element in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an object in a `function`:

```
createObject(attr) {
    return {
        attr: "test"
    }
}
```

I want the `attr` to be named by the `function parameter`.  Right now I end up with this object:

```
{
    attr: "test"
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: square-bracket notation

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-to-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 4):

Create a new object and use bracket notation to set the property.

```
function createObject(attr) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[attr] = "test";
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this pen to show you how to construct the object:

http://codepen.io/dieggger/pen/pJXJex

```
//function receiving the poarameter to construct the object
var createObject = function(attr) {
  //custom object with one predefined value.
   var myCustomObject = {
    anything: "myAnything",
  };

 //adding property to the object 
  myCustomObject[attr] = "Test";

 //returning the constructed object
  return myCustomObject;

}

//invoking function and assigning the returned object to a variable
var objReturned = createObject("name");

//simple alert , to test if it worked
alert(objReturned.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way?

```
createObject(attrName) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[attrName] = 'test';
    return obj;
}
```