# Handling input change depending on the number of key value pairs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose we have this form right here full of key values pairs (i.e. in this case)

```
const data = {
  maxPosts: 9999999,
  key: "value"
};
```

However there can be more key-value pairs and hence more inputs in the picture below.

What is a good way of handling the input change depending on the data given? Because I cannot hardcode all the input handlers like such (as the inputs are dependent on the KV Pairs):

```
      changeKey1: function (event) {
        // change state
      },
      changeVal1: function (event) {
        // Change State
      },
      changeKey2: function (event) {
        // Change State
      },
```

Ultimately the user will be editing these values and then press submit to confirm their edit changes. Is there anyway of doing this with React Hooks?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generic event handler to set the state of any form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065940/generic-event-handler-to-set-the-state-of-any-form-field) and [React.js: Identifying different inputs with one onChange handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029999)

Comment: @adiga I was wondering if the same behaviour could be replicated with React Hooks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [here is a simple example](https://jslwy.codesandbox.io/) of managing `N` states.

```js
const generateNValues = N => [...Array(N).keys()];

function TextAreaManager() {
  const [valuesManager, setValuesManager] = useState(generateNValues(10));
  return (
    <Flexbox>
      {valuesManager.map((value, i) => (
        <TextBoxItem
          key={i}
          value={value}
          onChange={e => {
            valuesManager[i] = e.target.value;
            setValuesManager([...valuesManager]);
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <PinkButton
        onClick={() =>
          setValuesManager([...Array(valuesManager.length).fill('')])
        }
      >
        Reset All
      </PinkButton>
    </Flexbox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit OS Q 556724228 - Manage dynamic form state]