# Change Leaflet overlay title for translated strings

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to hide/show some polygones on a map but in all examples I've found, including [the official one](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/), the overlay title is statically set:

```
var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities
};
```

What if instead of "Cities" I want to have a translated string? In the rest of my Javascript code, I call the translated strings with:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: Settings.base_url
...
}
```

or

```
$('#location_length').html(length_meters+' '+Settings.meters);
```

But if I try to use the following for the overlay, I get syntax error:

```
var overlayMaps = {
    Settings.show_polygone: cities
};
```

Settings.show_polygone is defined in my footer, for example:

```
show_polygone: "<?php echo $this->lang->line('main')['show_polygone']; ?>"
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: My guess is that it expects a string, and you are passing a object ? Maybe try converting it to a string.

Comment: I tried to add `var show_polygone = String(Settings.show_polygone);` and then `show_polygones: cities` but it displays `show_polygones`. Adding the String function directly also returns a syntax error.

Comment: try using the `.toString()` function. `var show_polygone = Settings.show_polygone.toString();`

Comment: Same problem if I use what you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [square bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable) if you want to set a variable as a key on a JS object.

Try

```
var overlays = {};
overlays[Settings.show_polygone] = cities;
```

And a demo

```js
var cities = L.layerGroup();

L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);


var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: mbAttr}),
    streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets',   attribution: mbAttr});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [grayscale, cities]
});

var baseLayers = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
    "Streets": streets
};

var Settings = {
    show_polygone: "Show polygons"
}

var overlays = {};
overlays[Settings.show_polygone] = cities;

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```