# How to use variables in MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use a variables in MongoDB's query like this?

```
var FOO="123";
var BOO="323";
user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userID},{$set:{FOO:BOO}}
```

BOO - the value, is working fine and it's being assign, while FOO - the key is not.

Comment: No, in MongoDB Foo is not a variable but a key "FOO" not FOO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In MongoDB as such no functionality but you can do this in javascript
>   like this

```
    var FOO="123";
    var BOO="323";
    user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userID},{$set:{[FOO]:BOO}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain why this syntax actually works?

Comment: @AndriySimonov you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Comment: @ManjeetThakur Thanks - PhpStorm doesn't recognize this syntax...but the code is running ..

Comment: @RoyBarOn Please accept the answer if this is working for you