# Bracket syntax problem in React Native -- possibly only a JavaScript syntax issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, syntax

I'm trying to map an array and reference the `.map()` parameters '`button`' and '`i`', in my React Native JSX. Feel like I've tried everything at this point. How do I correctly reference `button` and `i` as an item in my `styles` object within a JSX style prop? is this not possible?

```
{buttonSet.map(function(button, i) {
  let pleaseHelpMe = button + `${i}`;
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
    style={[styles.abacusButton, styles.pleaseHelpMe]}
    ...
    >
      <Text>X</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
})}
```

Comment: you have a typo `${i]}` has a closing array bracket... change to `${i}`. Also can you give an example of what `buttonSet` is? And also what your `styles` are? Why would you be defining a style for every button by their index?

Comment: `i]` is invalid syntax and `pleaseHelpMe` is not the same as `styles.pleaseHelpMe`

Comment: @ slebetman, sorry, that typo doesn't exist in my actual code, just my simplification here. I'll edit it.

Comment: If you want to dynamically reference a key in an object then you access it via, `styles[pleaseHelpMe]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` notation when you want to access property using variable,

```
{buttonSet.map(function(button, i) {
  let pleaseHelpMe = button + `${i}`;
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
    style={[styles.abacusButton, styles[pleaseHelpMe]]}
    ...
    >
      <Text>X</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. would you believe I've been trying to figure this out for 3 hours? Thank you kind sir. Will accept answer when the five minute time limit is up