# Can constants be introduced into a ReactJSS stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jss

Using ReactJSS, I've built a stylesheet that looks like this:

```
const styleSheet = {
  mainContainer: {
    height: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modalBodyContainer: {
    overflowY: 'auto'
  },
  '@media (min-width: 576px)': {
    modalBodyContainer: {
      padding: '0 100px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(80vh - 185px)'
    }
  },
  errorStateDropdown: {
    border: [['1px solid red'], '!important']
  }
};

export default styleSheet;
```

I'm now just starting to introduce some responsive code, as illustrated by this line: `'@media (min-width: 576px)'`

Rather than repeat `576px` over & over, I'd prefer to set it to a constant and reuse the constant.

The ReactJSS documentation is quite sparse so I can't figure out if this is possible.  If you have a suggestion, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Answer (score 2):

`Stylesheet` is a regular javascript `object`.

```
const height = '518px'
const minWidth = '500px'

const styleSheet = {
  mainContainer: {
    height,
    display: condition ? 'flex' : 'block',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modalBodyContainer: {
    overflowY: 'auto'
  },
  [`@media (min-width: ${minWidth})`]: {
    modalBodyContainer: {
      padding: '0 100px',
      maxHeight: getMaxHeight()
    }
  },
  errorStateDropdown: {
    border: [['1px solid red'], '!important']
  }
};

export default styleSheet;
```

Comment: You're missing the brackets around the dynamic property key.

Comment: Thanks as always ^^

Comment: @Dupocas thanks for your feedback.  It turns out that my linter didn't like me using the media query more than once.  So, instead, I just have it once near the end of the styleSheet object and then group all of the "desktop only" CSS code therein.  This works well and arguably better because now a new developer can instantly see all of the modifications for the non-mobile view.  It thus follows the best practice of "Mobile First".

Comment: Yes that is the pattern, you should have just one media query per size and group all your classes inside it