# create a javascript key value object dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

Create a javascript object with one key but multiple value
I want something like this created with a for loop

```
'Addresses': {
            '91e3e4ec8fbfc57477e05ca58679d830a2982a49a8d3fe60119ca84d640028ef': {
              'ChannelType': 'APNS',
              'Substitutions': {}
            },
           'test@test.com': {
              'ChannelType': 'EMAIL',
              'Substitutions': {}
            },


          }`
```

so addresses is the key, but inside the value of the key there is another key value pair. How do i create this dynamically in javascript?

what i have tried is

```
 for(var i = 0; i < data.EndpointsResponse.Item.length; i++) {

    address[data.EndpointsResponse.Item[i].Address] = {
      'ChannelType':
      data.EndpointsResponse.Item[i].ChannelType
    };
```

but it is creating it in the format

```
   'Addresses': {
            '91e3e4ec8fbfc57477e05ca58679d830a2982a49a8d3fe60119ca84d640028ef': 
              'ChannelType': 'APNS',
              'Substitutions': {}
            ,
           'test@test.com': 
              'ChannelType': 'EMAIL',
              'Substitutions': {}
            ,


          }`
```

which is different from what i want

Comment: By using either dynamic property names or square bracket notation for property access.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a useful answer if you supply a short example of the source of your data. A list that can be easily copied and pasted would work well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Comment: Looks like you should do your own homework and a little research, or at least make an attempt to solve it first before coming here and getting someone else to do it for you.. I gave a downvote.

Comment: spangle here is what I tried
   for(var i = 0; i < data.EndpointsResponse.Item.length; i++) {
        
        address[data.EndpointsResponse.Item[i].Address] = {
          'ChannelType':
          data.EndpointsResponse.Item[i].ChannelType
        };

      }
Happy?????

Comment: Please add that to your question above, also please give an example of what that the data looks like in your question above.

Comment: Your second code block is not legal javascript so that's simply not valid which makes the question hard to do anything with.

Answer (score -1):

Even when you put less than necessary in the question, ill try to answering doing my best.

You should create a object dynamically passing the key in a variable...

For example, if you have a array of strings you can walk into and use the value as key of a new object...

```
const arrayofString= ["key1", "key2", "key3"];
let objectnew = {}
arrayofString.forEach(item => {
  objectnew[item] = "value for item"
})
```

If you look a little bit through internet you can find many solve for this. Like this, for example: [Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)