# Updating state variable on click to show different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am new to React and try to load different components based on state variables. I want my handler to dynamically know which state variable I am updating. As of now, I am explicitly passing the state name as a string.

**State Variables**

```
state = {
        showLogin: false,
        showHome: false
    }
```

**Handler Method**

```
handleShow = (element) => this.setState({ element: true });
```

**Buttons**

```
{
  !this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Button
      variant="outline-primary"
      onClick={() => this.handleShow("showLogin")}
    >
      Login
    </Button>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Button
        variant="outline-primary"
        onClick={() => this.handleShow("showHome")}
      >
        Home
      </Button>
      <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={this.authorizeUserMethod}>
        LogOut
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Comment: No @Ksav.  My question is more related to 'element' here. I am passing state variable as string eg: "showLogin", "showHome" but it not working. How can I pass the name of the state variable dynamically?

Comment: `element` is a variable. The linked question deals with how to use the variable as a dynamic object key.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
handleShow = element => this.setState({
    ...this.state, 
    [element]: true
});
```

Comment: My question is more related to 'element' here. I am passing state variable as string eg: "showLogin", "showHome" but it not working. How can I pass the name of the state variable dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

In your handler method, you must use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), this allow you create a clone of your state and thus concatenate a new value.

**Handler Method**

```
handleShow = (element) => this.setState({ ...this.state, [element]: true });
```