# How to return an object value whose key is provided as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I’d like to know if it is possible to create a function that returns a field from an object given in parameter.

```js
const data = {
  "name": "Doe",
  "firstName": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "from": "USA"
};

function returnField(field) {
  return data.field;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable

Answer (score 1):

yes, its possible by using `[]` instead of `.`

```
data = {
 "name" : "doe",
 "firstname" : "jhon",
 "age" : 30,
 "from" : usa
 }

function returnField(field){
    return data[field]
}
```

In general you dont even need the function for it (unless you want to have more logic or some validation there) and just using `data[field]` directly.