# why string interpolation with backticks isn't working on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, interpolation, string-interpolation

I'm working in a personal project and I was trying to implement a string interpolation, but for some reason it isn't working and it is throwing an error.
I'm using visual studio code and the errors it's throwing are the following:

1. Property assignement expected
2. ';' expected (2 times)
3. Declaration or statement expected

this is the line where I put the specific interpolation:

```
newsection = {`${newsectionnmb}`:"placeholder"}
```

this is my complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink, match } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


class AddContent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            content: "",
            courseName:"",
            actualContent: [],
            section:"NEW",
            video: ""
        }

        
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/course/id/${Number(this.props.match.params.id)}`)
        .then( (response)=> {
            this.setState({
            courseName: response.data.name,
            actualContent: response.data.content
            });
            if(this.props._id != response.data.adminId) {
                this.props.history.push("/");
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert("we couldn't fetch the course data, try again later by reloading the page")
        })
          
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
    
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      }
    
      handleSubmit= (event)=> {
        if (this.state.name !== "" ) {
            if (this.state.section === "NEW") {
                newsectionnmb = this.state.actualContent.length +1;
                newsection = {`${newsectionnmb}`:"placeholder"}
            }
            event.preventDefault();

            axios({
                method: 'put',
                url: `http://localhost:5000/course/add-content/${Number(this.props.match.params.id)}`,
                data: {
                content: this.state.content
                }
                
                })
            }
      }

    render() {
    let sectionlist = this.state.actualContent.length > 0
        && this.state.actualContent.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <option key={i} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
      )
    }, this);
        return (
            <div className="courses">
                {this.props.registered === true?
                <div>
                    
                    
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="Register">
                    <h1>Add guide</h1>
                <h2>{this.state.courseName}</h2>
                <p>quotation marks aren't allowed</p>
                <div>
                    <input             
            name="name"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="name"/>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input             
            name="video"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="URL for video"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                
                    <textarea             
            name="content"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="content"/>
            </div>
            <label>select section:</label>
  <select name="section" onChange={this.handleChange} className="select">
    <option value="NEW">New Section</option>
            {sectionlist}
  </select>
            <button type="submit" className="coursesub">Submit</button>
            <NavLink exact to="/courses">Go back to course</NavLink>
            </form>




                </div>
                

                
                :
                <div>
                <h1>Welcome to SSG courses app, to start using please login.</h1>
                <NavLink exact to="/login">Login</NavLink>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default withRouter(AddContent);
```

Comment: :"placeholder" should be inside the string template.

Comment: like this? `newsection = {`"${newsectionnmb}":"placeholder"`}`

Comment: does not work, the same, if not worse

Comment: `newsection = {\`${newsectionnmb}:"placeholder"\`}`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Comment: You didn't really specify what your desired result was so I must have guessed incorrectly. You could probably reduce this example down to the bare minimum that illustrates the problem so that others can reproduce as well.

Comment: my trouble is with the interpolation

Comment: What I want it is that it stops throwing an error

Comment: Delete the line. No more error.

Comment: Thats not actuallly fun, you know what I mean

Comment: I obviously need that line, if I didn't It wouldn't be there

Comment: and If I knew how to reproduce it I would do it, but I don't know where the error comes from, so in an example the error probably wouldn't exist

Comment: and I'm alone...., I guess I'm gonna leave and check it  on the morning

Comment: You could also [edit] your question, as others have asked, to show where the errors are being thrown, and to make it clear what the expected outcome is. Otherwise we're guessing. Saying the expected outcome is "the errors are not thrown" is not helpful, to say the least. We want to know what you expect your code to do if the errors are not thrown. Please read [ask] and the pages linked therein for more.

Comment: for next time, thank for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make newsection an object, it should be done like this

```
newsection = {newsectionnmb:"placeholder"}
```

If you are trying to make it a string, this should work for you

```
newsection = `${newsectionnmb}:"placeholder"`
```

Comment: I was over complicating myself