# Remove entries from an object where the keys aren't in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to remove entries from an object so that it only includes those that are in an array. So I have a `required` array:

```
const required = ['accountNumber', 'packRequested', 'collectionDate']
```

And a `touchedFields` object:

```
const touchedFields = {
    accountNumber: true,
    sortCode: false,
    account: true,
    collectionDate: false,
    packRequested: false
}
```

This is what I am after:

```
const touchedFields = {
        accountNumber: true,
        collectionDate: false,
        packRequested: false
    }
```

How can this be achieved?

I've tried instead creating an array output (as I couldn't do the object), looping through each object entry, and the looping through each array key, comparing values and pushing to a new array if the values matches:

```
let newArr = []
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(requiredFields)) {
    Object.keys(touchedFields).forEach((cur) => {
        if (cur == value) {
            newArr.push({cur: value})
        }
    })
}
console.log(newArr)
```

But even that doesn't set the values properly as it set's the key as cur and not the actual cur variable:

```
[{cur: 'accountNumber'}, {cur: 'packRequested'}, {cur: 'collectionDate'}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to alter the orginal object, you can loop over the keys and delete the ones that are not in the required array.

```js
const required = ['accountNumber', 'packRequested', 'collectionDate']

const touchedFields = {
  accountNumber: true,
  sortCode: false,
  account: true,
  collectionDate: false,
  packRequested: false
}

const pruneObject = (obj, keys) => Object.keys(obj).forEach(
  key => !required.includes(key) && delete obj[key]
);

pruneObject(touchedFields, required);
console.log(touchedFields);
```

If you do not want to alter the original object you can loop over the array and build a new object from it.

```js
const required = ['accountNumber', 'packRequested', 'collectionDate']

const touchedFields = {
  accountNumber: true,
  sortCode: false,
  account: true,
  collectionDate: false,
  packRequested: false
}

const inclusivePick = (obj, keys) => Object.fromEntries(
  keys.map(key => [key, obj[key]])
);


const result = inclusivePick(touchedFields, required);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.reduce` method

```js
const required = ['accountNumber', 'packRequested', 'collectionDate']

const touchedFields = {
  accountNumber: true,
  sortCode: false,
  account: true,
  collectionDate: false,
  packRequested: false
}

const result = required.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = touchedFields[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const required = ['accountNumber', 'packRequested', 'collectionDate']

const touchedFields = {
    accountNumber: true,
    sortCode: false,
    account: true,
    collectionDate: false,
    packRequested: false
}

let result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(touchedFields)
  .filter(([k,v]) => required.includes(k))
)

console.log(result)
```