# How to set key in dictionary using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use a variable as a key in dictionary using Firestore.

```
var uid = "123456";

await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("shop")
          .doc(shopId)
          .update({
            "role.${uid}": "reader",
          });
```

But this above code doesn't work.

The result is here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cACRn.png)

How do I set the `uid` to `role`'s key?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable

Comment: I already tried `role[uid]`. But in this context the role dictionary doesn't be identified. Because only inside Firesotre data  it is identified.
So complier issued a error. `No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'role'. Either declare one or provide an initializer`

Comment: If you want it to be `{ "role.123456" : "reader"}` it is `const uid = 123; var y = { [\`role.${uid}\`]: "reader" }; console.log(y);`

Comment: It did work. Thank you. First I thought I should do `role[uid]`. But to create dynamic a dictionary should I use `[]` for overall,  right? Is this the same way you showed me as the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should be using a template literal (backticks) instead of a regular string (double-quotes).

eg:

```js
await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("shop")
          .doc(shopId)
          .update({
            [`role.${uid}`]: "reader",
          });
```

Comment: that is not going to work. You are going to get an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected template string`

Comment: You are absolutely right - fixed it now

Comment: It did success. Why is it a right way? I have not seen using both `[]` and `$()` simultaneously. If you know about the tips, please teach me.

Comment: The square brackets allow you to specify the key to set in the object you are passing to `update` using an expression rather than a symbol. The `${}` is performing the substitution in the string that is actually specifying the key.

The `update` method sees none of this, and only receives the final result: an object that looks like `{ "role.123456" : "reader" }`