# Shopify cart values only update when I use hardcoded values

Tags: javascript, fetch, shopify, shopify-api

I have written some code to allow my client to add free products to cart when its value goes above a fixed threshold.

I get these values in my file through the theme settings. The problem is that the free product code only works if I use hardcoded values. Otherwise, I get 404 erro in the cart update.js file.

This is the code that works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var total_cart_price = 0;
        total_cart_price = data.total_price / 100;
        var free_product_id = settings.first_free_product;
        var first_free_price_threshold = settings.first_free_price_threshold;
        console.log(Free product ID: ${free_product_id} and price threshold: ${first_free_price_threshold});

        const cartItems = data.items.map(item => item.id);
        let updates = {};
        if (total_cart_price < 60) {
            updates = {
                48270424670533: 0
            };
        }
        if (total_cart_price >= 60) {
            updates = {
                48270424670533: 1
            };
        }
        fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/update.js', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                updates
            })
        }).then(response => {
            myCartRefresher();
            return response.json();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
});
```

This is the code that doesn't:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var total_cart_price = 0;
        total_cart_price = data.total_price / 100;
        var free_product_id = {{ settings.first_free_product }};
        var first_free_price_threshold = {{ settings.first_free_price_threshold }};
        console.log(Free product ID: ${free_product_id} and price threshold: ${first_free_price_threshold});

        const cartItems = data.items.map(item => item.id);
        let updates = {};
        if (total_cart_price < first_free_price_threshold) {
            updates = {
                free_product_id: 0
            };
        }

        if (total_cart_price >= first_free_price_threshold) {
            updates = {
                free_product_id: 1
            };
        }
        fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/update.js', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                updates
            })
        }).then(response => {
            myCartRefresher();
            return response.json();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of key/object looks a bit broken.

Try this:

```
        if (total_cart_price < first_free_price_threshold) {
            updates = {
                [free_product_id]: 0
            };
        }

        if (total_cart_price >= first_free_price_threshold) {
            updates = {
                [free_product_id]: 1
            };
        }
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks. :)

The documentation (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-locale-cart-update-js) uses this syntax: 

```
let updates = {
  794864053: 0,
  794864233: 0
};
```

Are we supposed to use `[]` when using variables?

Comment: @RealNoob that's right. But if we need to create dynamic object kee to specify the product id, we should tell JS that it is variable and not static string.
Here are some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462800/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-key-to-be-added-to-a-javascript-object-variable